ProcessRunner unable to run process upsert java.lang.NullPointerException
I have some problems with automate process with dataloader CLI. When doing the upsert process there is an error after mapping fields, but I don't know which part contains NullPointerExecption, has anyone ever experienced this issue?
this is a log result:
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Start Mon 06/03/2024 15:01:05.79                                                    
  Interface     = RDSBox                                
  New           = D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\workingFolder                                  
  ToLoad        = D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\toLoad                                 
  Error         = D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\errors                                     
  Archive Diff  = D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\archive\diff                               
  Archive Full  = D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\archive\full                               
  Script        = D:\Application\Consoles\SFDL_AXA_CONF                                     
  Log           = D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\log                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Copying new file to workingFolder... Please wait... 
Generating diff file... Please wait... 
Upserting diff file... Please wait(takes some time)... 
2024-06-03 15:01:06,135 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:396) - Using built-in logging configuration, no log-conf.xml in D:\Application\Consoles\SFDL_AXA_CONF\log-conf.xml
2024-06-03 15:01:06,135 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:398) - The log has been initialized
2024-06-03 15:01:06,135 INFO  [main] process.ProcessConfig getBeanFactory (ProcessConfig.java:104) - Loading process configuration from config file: D:\Application\Consoles\SFDL_AXA_CONF\configSandbox\process-conf.xml
2024-06-03 15:01:06,213 INFO  [main] support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:495) - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@53e25b76: startup date [Mon Jun 03 15:01:06 ICT 2024]; root of context hierarchy
2024-06-03 15:01:06,246 INFO  [main] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315) - Loading XML bean definitions from file [D:\Application\Consoles\SFDL_AXA_CONF\configSandbox\process-conf.xml]
2024-06-03 15:01:06,309 INFO  [main] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557) - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1936f0f5: defining beans [AccountClient,AccountBankStaff,AccountBusinessAccount,Application,Claim,InsurancePolicy,DeliveryInformation,PolicyOwnerService,Payment,CustomerPortfolio,VarCompASMCarPath,VarCompASMValidation,VarCompASMCompensation,VarCompFACarPath,VarCompFACompensation,VarCompFAValidation,VarCompRegMgrCarPath,PersonalInformation,TrainingAllowance,MedicalBenefit,VariableCompensation,BasicAllowance,ValidationDemotion,SuperFA,BPP,RDSBox]; root of factory hierarchy
2024-06-03 15:01:06,342 INFO  [RDSBox] controller.Controller initConfig (Controller.java:334) - config dir created at D:\Application\Consoles\SFDL_AXA_CONF\configSandbox
2024-06-03 15:01:06,928 INFO  [RDSBox] controller.Controller initConfig (Controller.java:362) - The controller config has been initialized
2024-06-03 15:01:06,928 INFO  [RDSBox] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:116) - Initializing process engine
2024-06-03 15:01:06,928 INFO  [RDSBox] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:119) - Loading parameters
2024-06-03 15:01:06,928 INFO  [RDSBox] config.LastRun load (LastRun.java:96) - Last run info will be saved in file: D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\log\RDSBox_lastRun.properties
2024-06-03 15:01:06,944 INFO  [RDSBox] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:127) - Logging in to: https://axa-id-dp--sit.sandbox.my.salesforce.com
2024-06-03 15:01:06,944 INFO  [RDSBox] client.PartnerClient login (PartnerClient.java:479) - Beginning Partner Salesforce login ....
2024-06-03 15:01:06,944 INFO  [RDSBox] client.ClientBase getConnectorConfig (ClientBase.java:124) - Salesforce login will use proxy host: proxyid.axa-id.intraxa port: 8080
2024-06-03 15:01:06,959 INFO  [RDSBox] client.PartnerClient loginInternal (PartnerClient.java:523) - Salesforce login to https://axa-id-dp--sit.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/40.0 as user lms.sysadmin@axa.co.id.sit
2024-06-03 15:01:07,767 INFO  [RDSBox] client.ClientBase getConnectorConfig (ClientBase.java:124) - Salesforce login will use proxy host: proxyid.axa-id.intraxa port: 8080
2024-06-03 15:01:07,782 INFO  [RDSBox] dao.DataAccessObjectFactory getDaoInstance (DataAccessObjectFactory.java:51) - Instantiating data access object: D:\AXA_INDO\RDSBox\workingFolder\newRDSBox.csv of type: csvRead
2024-06-03 15:01:07,782 INFO  [RDSBox] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:132) - Checking the data access object connection
2024-06-03 15:01:07,782 INFO  [RDSBox] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:137) - Setting field types
2024-06-03 15:01:08,367 INFO  [RDSBox] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:141) - Setting object reference types
2024-06-03 15:01:09,159 INFO  [RDSBox] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:145) - Creating Map
2024-06-03 15:01:09,159 FATAL [main] process.ProcessRunner topLevelError (ProcessRunner.java:238) - Unable to run process RDSBox
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:162)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:100)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:253)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1192)
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1186)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:552)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.Mapper.<init>(Mapper.java:87)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.LoadMapper.<init>(LoadMapper.java:51)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createMapper(Controller.java:195)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:146)
    ... 2 more
Archiving diff and new files... Please wait... 
Some cleaning... Please wait... 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
End Mon 06/03/2024 15:01:09.25                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
*** Directory for new files does not exists. ***
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
End Mon 06/03/2024 15:01:09.25                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 


I used config.properties to setup endpoint, username, password etc.
config.properties:
#Loader Config
#Mon Feb 11 2013
dataAccess.readUTF8=true
dataAccess.writeUTF8=true
process.enableExtractStatusOutput=true
process.enableLastRunOutput=true
process.encryptionKeyFile=D:\\Application\\Consoles\\configSandbox\\key.txt
sfdc.bulkApiCheckStatusInterval=5000
sfdc.bulkApiSerialMode=5000
sfdc.debugMessages=false
sfdc.enableRetries=true
sfdc.endpoint=https://xxx.my.salesforce.com
sfdc.extractionRequestSize=500
sfdc.insertNulls=true
sfdc.loadBatchSize=200
sfdc.maxRetries=3
sfdc.minRetrySleepSecs=2
sfdc.noCompression=false
sfdc.password=***
sfdc.timeoutSecs=60
sfdc.useBulkApi=false
sfdc.username=****
sfdc.proxyHost=proxyid.axa-id.intraxa
sfdc.proxyPort=8080
dataAccess.type=csvRead

and this is a process-conf.xml file for upsert process:
<bean id="RDSBox" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
        <description>Upsert RDSBox</description>
        <property name="name" value="RDSBox"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="D:\RDSBox\workingFolder\newRDSBox.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.lastRunOutputDirectory" value="D:\RDSBox\log"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="..\configSandbox\RDSBox.sdl"/>
                <entry key="process.statusOutputDirectory" value="D:\RDSBox\log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="RDS_Box__c"/>
                <entry key="process.outputError" value="D:\RDSBox\errors\ErrorRDSBox.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="D:\RDSBox\loaded\LoadedRDSUpsert.csv"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Key__c"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="upsert"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

I used dataloader v54.0.0
